# Fechar todas as Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Possuo 3 *activities*:

- `splash_screen`
- `MainActivity`
- `error_webview`

A *activity* `error_webview` tem  dois botões, um para abrir a `splash_screen` e outro para fechar (Sair), porém queria que ao clicar em "Sair" ele fechasse todas as *activities* e o aplicativo não ficasse aberto.

Abaixo o código fonte da minha `error_webview` para quem puder me ajudar.

```
package conectaluziania.conectaluziania;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentCallbacks;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import prosportacademia.prosportacademia.MainActivity;
import prosportacademia.prosportacademia.R;
import prosportacademia.prosportacademia.splash_screen;

public class error_webview extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_error_webview);

/*Abre uma nova atividade Caso a internet não funcione*/
        OnClickListener listnr=new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i= new Intent("splash_screen");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
        Button btn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(listnr);

/*Fim da Abertura da Atividade */

/*Inicio: Fecha a atividade quando clicar em Sair */

/*Fim: Fecha a atividade quando clicar em Sair */




    }
}
```

Comment: Se a app for para Android 4.1(Api 16) ou superior pode usar [finishAffinity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity())

Answer (score 1):

Essa resposta foi feita com base em uma do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14002030/8839059), mas acrescentei alguns detalhes.

Em primeiro lugar, vamos voltar para a `Activity` inicial (a que inicia junto do seu App):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), splash_screen.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Caso a sua `splash_screen` esteja na sua *backstack*, a *flag* [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) irá encerrar todas as outras `Activity` e voltar para a inicial.  Caso você tenha encerrado a `splash_screen` para iniciar a `MainActivity`, basta trocar a classe no código.

O [`putExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) está enviando uma mensagem para a sua `splash_screen` (ou `MainActivity`) que deve possuir o seguinte código no `onCreate`:

```java
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
```

O [`getBooleanExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getBooleanExtra(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) simplesmente está procurando se existe um valor definido para o `EXIT`. Se existir (o que acontecerá quando você clicar no botão sair), a `Activity` será encerrada.

Ou seja: primeiro encerramos todas `Activity` mandando um sinal para a primeira da *backstack* encerrar, então ela receberá o sinal e também se encerrará, com isso não restará nenhuma `Activity` aberta e o aplicativo será fechado.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um exemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615431/close-all-running-activities-in-an-android-application) [SOLUTION 2] que explica exatamente o que você quer saber!

Outra forma, se for o caso de fechar a activity e o aplicativo, poderia ser:

```
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

no listener do botão.